# Execute arbitrary code when python starts? I try edit __loader__

Tags: python

```
.../python3.10/importlib $ python
Python 3.10.5 (main, Jun  7 2022, 03:53:14) [Clang 12.0.8 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project c935d99d7 on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> globals()
{'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None, '__loader__': <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, '__spec__': None, '__annotations__': {}, '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>}
>>> __loader__
<class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
>>> __loader__.test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'BuiltinImporter' has no attribute 'test'
>>> __import__('_frozen_importlib').__file__
'/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/_bootstrap.py'
>>>
[17]+  Stopped                 python
.../python3.10/importlib $ cd '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/'
.../python3.10/importlib $ grep -rn "class BuiltinImporter"
_bootstrap.py:724:class BuiltinImporter:
.../python3.10/importlib $ echo "i will add 'test' attribute to 'BuiltinImporter' class"
i will add 'test' attribute to 'BuiltinImporter' class
.../python3.10/importlib $ nano _bootstrap.py
.../python3.10/importlib $ grep -rn "test="
_bootstrap.py:731:    test= "Hi!"
.../python3.10/importlib $ python
Python 3.10.5 (main, Jun  7 2022, 03:53:14) [Clang 12.0.8 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project c935d99d7 on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> __loader__
<class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
>>> __loader__.test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'BuiltinImporter' has no attribute 'test'
>>> # how can make this work?
>>>
```

Ultimately I want to force separate code to be executed when python starts.  for example, change the BuiltinImporter class so that it does `print(1)` and 1 should be output when python starts. I tried to change this class, but apparently it is built into python.  how can execute arbitrary code when python starts?

Comment: If you are interested only on interactive python, you can add any python code to .pythonrc file and everything in that file gets executed at the startup..

Comment: @rasjani, what about a ordinary python that executes .py files?

Comment: You already control that by giving your python script as argument but you can use site-customize.py script too. Run `python -c "import sitecustomize; print(sitecustomize)"` and edit the file in the output ..